# CE and FCC for MCU boards/Raspberry Pi HATs/Arduino shields etc

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, fcc, certification, ce

There doesn't seem to be a great deal of information on the internet about this (and the information that there is is usually contradicted somewhere else), so I'm going to ask this here, in the hope that somebody has experience with it.

Are there exceptions from CE, or FCC compliance for boards such as HATS/Arduino shields etc... which are unintentional radiators? Most boards like this that are sold seem to not be tested, and basically, I'm asking whether this is just a case of the rules not being enforced for small quantities, or if there are genuine exceptions (such as if they count as subassemblies).

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how you look at it. Every product that is considered an end-user product must have a CE certification. I don't know how the FCC works, but in the case of CE it's self-certification. That means you may just state that your product is CE compliant and that's it. Of course you are always responsible for your product (even if a third party has verified EMC compliance and such). If it ends up interfering with other appliances of injuring someone, your in trouble.

That said... CE is not requires for "component or modules" that are used to manufacture end-products - which one might argue an arduio is. Or is it? Maybe it's a consumer product designed for education and developing. Not sure myself.

I personally think it's still a niche product that is not a standalone device. But I'm no lawyer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Have spent a lot of time researching this recently and wanted to add to this

You can see that on the official Arduino site, the genuine article does have the CE and FCC markings and you can even see results of tests for some of them
[[Official Arduino Nano](http://store.arduino.cc/collections/boards/products/arduino-nano-every)][1](http://store.arduino.cc/collections/boards/products/arduino-nano-every)

While smaller components such as sensors and breakout boards on other public sites don't have these markings and somehow able to sell them
I don't meant eBay or Amazon sellers but proper vendors that sell at a higher price

This seems to indicate that smaller components are not in scope of these directives and a complete Arduino is